# how to modify Grub or mgr so that I can boot into windows 7 instead of Neogrub

Tags: windows-7, boot, grub, bootmgr, easybcd

I have installed windows7 in C drive. Now I use easyBCD to install ubuntu. I followed the steps according to an article which teaches how to install ubuntu-windows dual system(not in English, so I don't paste the link here). I put the ubuntu ISO in C drive and t**hen use easybcd to set boot from **Neogrub** instead of windows7.** So the idea is that after I reboot the system, the system will load the ubuntu ISO image for installation.

However, since I made some mistakes. I failed in installing ubuntu and I cannot enter WINDOW7 again. Coz after booting, I always boot into Neogrub, and enter the interface which only shows "install ubuntu".

Later I installed ubuntu from USB(not in C drive), and now I still cannot enter windows7.

yes, there is a "WINDOWS7" option after booting, but when I click it, it just redirects to Neogrub, and "install ubuntu" instead of entering WINDOW7 system.

I checked C drive under ubuntu, and I see some files like `bootmgr, NeoGrub, OEMSF, pagefile.sys`, so what can I do so that I can enter windows 7 ?

I installed grub-customizer, and I notice the source for WINDOWS7 option is:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  BA484E09484DC53B
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root BA484E09484DC53B
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
chainloader +1
```

BTW, my grub info:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/8201414/

Answer (score 0):

If you can boot to Ubuntu, try installing GRUB customizer. To install GRUB customizer, enter these commands in a terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adabbas/1stppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

If you can't boot to Ubuntu, make a [live boot USB disk](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and use that to install GRUB and make changes. At first start, GRUB will look for all installed operating systems on the computer. Then you may modify your boot preferences. When you save any modifications, it will apply any fixes needed to boot windows correctly.

UPDATE: Since you've messed up windows bootloader pretty bad, try Boot-Repair:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

In the last tab you'll find a "repair windows boot files" check that and apply changes. [Read this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If that fails, try booting to a windows repair disk. That should override the ubuntu bootloader altogether: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader

Comment: after installation of grub-customizer, what are the next steps? I open it, but it only shows some items which i see when booting

Comment: Do you also see windows as an option there?

Comment: yes, but I also see "WINDOWS" option when I boot my laptop. When I click this option, it redirects to "install ubuntu" instead of windows7 system (this is because I put the ubuntu IOS image and its related booting stuff in C drive)

Comment: So you basically installed both ubuntu and windows into the same c drive?

Comment: No, ubuntu is installed in a spare division, not in C drive

Comment: I updated the answer. Try boot-repair.

Comment: I tried the boot-repair, but still I see "install ubuntu" after rebooting and click on the Windows7 option. is it because I have these files ```bootmgr, NeoGrub, OEMSF, pagefile.sys``` in C drive? they should be generated. when I use easyBCD for configuration Can I delete them?

Comment: the issue could be that I always boot into neogrub in C drive instead of windows, and if I delete NeoGrub, the booting will lead to "Can not find neogrub in all drives. Press Ctrl+AL+del" to restart